# Root cause for Connection broken for id 1, my id = 3, error =

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent 4 for kafka and zookeeper installation.

On our Kafka Cluster environment (of 3 brokers and 3 zookeeper nodes running on 3 aws instances) 
we are seeing a set of below warnings, repeatedly getting recorded in the broker's server.log file.

We have not observed any functionality issues due to this yet, but we are not able to find the root cause and there may be a chance in future it will affect the clients or other broker nodes. We are not sure yet about this. Below is the set of warnings

```
[2018-04-03 12:00:40,707] WARN Interrupted while waiting for message on queue (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
 at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:418)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:1097)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$700(QuorumCnxManager.java:74)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:932)
[2018-04-03 12:00:40,707] WARN Connection broken for id 1, my id = 3, error =  (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:1013)
[2018-04-03 12:00:40,708] WARN Interrupting SendWorker (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
[2018-04-03 12:00:40,707] WARN Send worker leaving thread (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
```

This set of warnings get repeated and getting observed in all 3 kafka nodes.

If anyone has any idea about why this warning gets generate, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this seems like zk logs, check the zk node with id 1.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a known issue with newer version of Zk, Check out this JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2938

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was replacing a ZK node and the old one was still running which I didn't realize. So I had created 2x nodes with the same "myid".